# Calculating a MLE for the combinatorial probability distribution: $\sum_k p^k(1-p)^{N-j-k}\binom{N-j}{k} \cdot(1-p)^{i-k}p^{j-i+k}\binom{j}{i-k}$

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, combinatorics

I have a relatively complicated discrete probability distribution:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(i;j) &= \sum_k p^k(1-p)^{N-j-k}\binom{N-j}{k}\cdot(1-p)^{i-k}p^{j-i+k}\binom{j}{i-k} \\
&= \frac{p^j}{p^i} \frac{(1-p)^i}{(1-p)^j} \sum_{k=0}^i p^{2k}(1-p)^{N-2k} \binom{N-j}{k} \binom{j}{i-k},
\end{aligned}$$

and I need to compute the maximum for the likelihood $\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}; j)$ for some $\vec{x}=\left<x_1,\ldots,x_n \right>, 0\leq x_t\leq N$ a sequence of naturals $i$ less than $N.$ To be clear: I'm fixing $p$ and I want to find the MLE for $j$.

As usual:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}; j) = \prod_{x_t}P(x_t;j)=P(0;j)^{a_0}P(1;j)^{a_1} \cdots P(N;j)^{a_N},
\end{aligned}$$

for $a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_N = n$.

Unfortunately, I cannot see a simple way to simplify $P(i;j)$, so computing this maximum likelihood is even worse. The usual trick of taking log doesn't seem to work because of the sum on the front. So:

1. Any advice on simplifying my expression for $P(i;j)$? (note: it's almost a Vandermonde).
2. Any tricks for computing the Maximum likelihood?

I'm ideally looking for analytic solutions.

Two small notes:

- $N$ and $p$ are fixed in the above, $N$ is a fixed value between 4 and 32 and $p$ is a probability (in my case it's $0.05$), in case that's helpful.
- $P(i;j)$ is coming from a convolution, which is probably obvious.

Comment: Your notation is difficult to decipher because the variables on one side of each equation never match those on the other.  In particular, your definition of $m_S(i)$ involves an undefined variable "$j$" and your likelihood references "$j$" on the left side but it never appears explicitly on the right.  Unless you are *perfectly* clear in your definitions, answering your question becomes a matter of guesswork.  An alternative is to explain the background for this problem so that readers can make sense of less-than-rigorous notation.

Comment: @whuber apologies, I've updated the probability notation to clearly indicate what they are.

Comment: This is a fairly common problem. One has something like

\begin{aligned}
Y=\sum_{k=1}^n  X_k
\end{aligned}

and is interested in computing $\log(Y)$, but $Y$ is too large  due to the large  size of the $X_k$.  However assume that  $\log(X_k)$ can be calculated. 
We can then implicitly divide by the largest $X$. Assume it is $X_1$

\begin{aligned}
Y=\sum_{k=1}^n  \exp(\log(X_k)-\log(X_1))\exp(n\log(X_1))
\end{aligned}
Then
\begin{aligned}
\log(Y)=\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  \exp(\log(X_k)-\log(X_1))\right)+ n\log(X_1)
\end{aligned}

So the overflow from the large $X_i$ is avoided.

Comment: Assuming that you are looking for the maximum likelihood estimator for $p$ given $j$, $N$, and $a_0, a_1, a_2,…,a_N$ (which I would say still isn't clear), is there some reason you believe that an explicit symbolic solution exists as opposed to an iterative, numerical solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

From simulating data from the multinomial distribution it appears that the nearest integer to $\bar{x}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate of $j$ a very high percentage of the time (as in maybe 99% of the time but not 100% of the time).  (I won't have time for a while to give all of the details of that inference but maybe in a few days I'll have time to document that appropriately.)

**End of update**

If $j$ is the parameter of interest, then I don't see that there is much simplification for the log of the likelihood.  In addition, because the legitimate values of $j$ range from $0$ to $N$, I think you'll just need to calculate the log likelihood for each of those values of $j$ and pick the (hopefully unique) value that maximizes the log of the likelihood.  (Setting the  derivative of the log likelihood with respect to $j$ to zero and solving for $j$ won't get you an integer value and there are not that many values of $j$ to consider in the first place.)

Here is some *Mathematica* code to do so:

First define $\log(P(i;j))$:

```
logP[i_, j_, p_, NN_] := (j - i) Log[p] + (i - j) Log[1 - p] +
  Log[Sum[p^(2 k) (1 - p)^(NN - 2 k) Binomial[NN - j, k] Binomial[j, i - k], {k, 0, i}]]
```

Now define the log of the likelihood for all legitimate values of $j$ given $p$ and the counts $a$:

```
logL[p_, a_] := Table[{j, N[a.Table[logP[i, j, p, Length[a] - 1], {i, 0, Length[a] - 1}]]},
  {j, 0, Length[a] - 1}]
```

As an example consider $p=1/20$ and $a=(1,2,4,5)$:

```
logLikelihood = logL[1/20, {1, 2, 4, 5}]
(* {{0, -68.8659}, {1, -43.224}, {2, -26.9353}, {3, -27.6437}} *)
maxLogLikelihood = Select[logLikelihood, #[[2]] == Max[logLikelihood[[All, 2]]] &]
(* {{2, -26.9353}} *)

ListPlot[{logLikelihood, maxLogLikelihood}, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.02]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

[image: j vs log of likelihood]

**Addition:**

Sometimes simplification is in the eye of the beholder.  The probability $P(i;j)$ can be written as

$$\binom{j}{i} p^{j-i} (1-p)^{i-j+N} \, _2F_1\left(-i,j-N;-i+j+1;\frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}\right)$$

where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function.

Comment: Sorry Jim, I didn't notice your comment. I am actually looking for the MLE for $j$, as I mention in the notes at the end, $p$ is fixed. I'm sorry for not being more clear. I'll edit the question to make this as clear as possible.

Comment: Ok.  And does $j$ potentially take on values restricted to $0, 1, \ldots, N$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the distribution of i is approximately normal for almost all N, j I tried.
See example
[image]

And after some tests, it looks like the maximum is always essentially at

$$i_{max} = p N + (1-2 p) j$$

See  the comparison between this equation and the experimentally determined max for $1<N<70$, $1<j<N$ and $p \sim Uniform(0,1)$

[image]

Essentially the true max is never further than one from the formula.

I am sure there is some clever math that proves it because the formula is so simple... Maybe seeing the answer, somebody here can figure out why the maximum is there.

EDIT: After writing the post, I figured that I wasn't quite answering the right question, as you cared about MLE not just maximum of P(i|j,N). But certainly you can try to adopt a Normal approximation, using the equation for the max as a center of the Gaussian. One only has to determine what is the width of the Gaussian.